# Android: How to update a cached fragment in swipe views?

Tags: android, caching, swipe

I have implemented swipe views in my app. The adapter is a FragmentStatePagerAdapter. The content in the fragments of the swipe view might influence each other.

Problem: The ViewPager caches one fragment to the left and one to the right. The changes made in one fragment are not reflected in the cached fragments to the left and the right. Only after enough swiping (so that the fragments are not in cache anymore and have to be rebuilt) the changes become visible.

I tried to disable this behavior with

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
```

but that didn't work. This might also slow down the swiping performance.

The next thing I tried was to overwrite onResume() in the fragment to update the content. However, it looks like, that onResume() is not called before swiping to that fragment.

Lastly, I tried this:

```
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) viewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(viewPager, position);
            TextView text = (TextView) fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("bla");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

This gives a NullPointerException on fragment, because instantiateItem does not return the corresponding Fragment, but the parent Activity.

Now, what is the recommended approach to update a cached fragment?

Comment: ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0) doesn't work, because the minimum of offscreen pages is 1.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26359308/refresh-fragment-in-viewpager-using-fragmentstatepageradapter) may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm under the impression, that I just shouldn't try to update a cached fragment. I think it would be made easier, if that would be meant to be done.

Therefore, I decided to refactor my app and moved the elements I wish to modify to the parent activity. The fragments now only contain elements specific to one fragment. This is probably a cleaner design anyway.